# Java vs .NET

Tags: .net, java

В универе стоит выбор между двумя направлениями в обучении: JAVA или .NET. С учетом не углубленного опыта работы с этими платформами, хотел бы узнать ваши аргументированые мнения по этому поводу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вопрос относящийся к разряду "холиварных" (примеры: Windows vs Linux и прочее)
И единственно верным путём выбора между этими платформами - это то к чему вам ближе.

.NET - Это чисто под Microsoft если вам нравится всё что делает эта компания и больше НИЧЕГО, то это платформа как раз для вас.

Java - Это для ВСЕГО! начиная от мобильников и заканчивая тем же Windows и Linux. Основная суть Java - Это запуск ваших программ под все возможные платформы. но конечно от, того что Java ориентирован для всего он немножко слабее в качестве функционала.

Поэтому вам выбирать, что лушче. Но моё мнение такое, я хочу знать и .net и Java чем собственно сейчас и занимаюсь.

Comment: Который раз вижу не совсем правильную трактовку концепций Java. Уже сто лет, как реальные деньги крутяться в энтерпрайзе. Десктопные и мобильные приложения не могут служить критерием выбора технологии (кстати под Windows Phone 7 программы пишуься именно на .Net). Сравнивая эти две технологии нужно в первую очередь оценивать их потенциал в нише энтерпрайза.
А мысль знать и Java и .Net очень здравая - поддерживаю.

Comment: а можно ли пример готовых продуктов, написанных на Java?

Comment: Java - апплеты для мобильников. Игра Minecraft
To Yevgen, верно, но я как бы указал, что .NET - это под всё что делает Microsoft: и WP7, и Xbox.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду говоря о готовых продуктах - конкретные настольные программы, или готовые решения для бизнеса?
Кстати, я помню тему про Java на десктопе: http://hashcode.ru/questions/3914/desktop-java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B

Comment: Ну заявлять, что .NET - только Microsoft - не совсем корректно (mono - оно подо всё, хотя сборки с gtk# и сборки с ms-библиотеками - они разные) (1). Набор языков под .NET существенно шире (2).

Comment: По поводу продуктов, выполненных на java: я вот работал в http://www.openwaygroup.com/ у них система Way4 была изначально написана на C/C++, но вот уже много лет переходит потихоньку на Java (Сейчас, наверное, большая часть написана на Java). Это банковская процессинговая система, на ней стоит множество банков  по всему миру, в том числе отчасти Сбер и другие наши гиганты

Comment: Да, это важный поинт. Java очень надёжна, и поэтому ей доверяют реальные деньги на торговых площадках, банках, биржах и т.п. Доверять хоть что-либо серьёзное mono - добровольное лишение себя сна ;) Я бы сказал, что доверять что-то связке .NET+Windows тоже не самая хорошая идея..

Answer (score 3):

Пока учитесь - учите оба. Потом сами решите.

Answer (score 0):

В свое время, пару лет назад, будучи еще на первом курсе выбрал в качестве основной платформы - Java. Java и как платформа мощная, и как язык, имеется множество фреймворков и библиотек облегчающих работу программиста. Не могу сказать, что .Net как платформа хуже, или обладает меньшими возможностями.
На обеих платформах при достаточных знаниях можно реализовать что угодно.
Делая выбор между двумя этими технологиями, на мой взгляд, необходимо в первую очередь ознакомится с ситуацией на рынке труда в вашем регионе. Какая технология более востребована, со знаниями какой технологии легче найти работу или с какой технологией большие перспективы.
Кроме меня, многие в институте выбрали .Net, а так как наш институт учавствует в партнерской программе Майкрософт, через декана многие нашли неплохую работу вообще без усилий. Так что мне кажется, что делая выбор между этими двумя промышленными стандартами, основываться нужно именно на ситуации на рынке.

Comment: да вот рынок как рас и спорный вопрос, потому что сейчас у Java кодеров высокая зп, а спрос начинает рости на .NET...

Comment: В большинстве банков на сегодняшний день используется Java EE. Я сомневаюсь, что массово будет принято решение перейти на .Net. Хотя утверждать наверняка невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Незнаю, у нас в универе был подобный выбор, я выбрал яву, ибо как мне кажется майкрософт в очень скором времени уйдет в небытие.

Comment: Да, вот только выпустят 8 винду и в небытие.... :) посмотрите соотношение всех остальных против винды... кто будет подымать всю эту кучу железа, если мелких не станет? а вот у явы мне кажется сейчас ступор в развитии

Comment: Временный ступор был связан с непростым положением в Sun перед крахом и определённой политикой руководства.

Comment: А крах Sun связан с тем, что в Java нет атрибутов :)

Comment: Как бы ява сейчас не ушла в полную Ж с ее нынешним владельцем.

Comment: О какой Ж вы говорите? Оракл очень много где используется. Я бы даже сказал, почти везде. Так что не говорите ерунды.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд - я бы выбрал из двух вариантов C# .NET, потому что: 
1) Более мощные языковые конструкции (linq, свойства, var-переменные, extensions-методы, etc)

2) На данный момент есть возможность разрабатывать под любую платформу (xamarin, asp, mono)

3) Достаточно много вакансий на данный момент, работу найти уже попроще.

А как бы другие ответили, спустя 5 лет?)